# iOS: reachability for AFNetworking

Tags: ios, reachability, afnetworking-2, afhttprequestoperation

I' doing a 'Batch of Operations' in this way and it work fine

```
NSMutableArray *mutableOperations = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSString *stringURL in url_list) {

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
        operation.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

            [self addDataToTotal:[self parseJSONfile:responseObject]];

        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];

        [mutableOperations addObject:operation];
    }

    NSArray *operations = [AFURLConnectionOperation batchOfRequestOperations:mutableOperations progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {
        NSLog(@"progress:%f", (float)numberOfFinishedOperations / totalNumberOfOperations);
    } completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {
        NSLog(@"All operations in batch complete");
        [self startPopulateDBStructure:self.total];
    }];
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperations:operations waitUntilFinished:NO];
```

now I want to use the 'reachability property' to check the connection status and I do this

```
[[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]reachabilityManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
        switch (status) {
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN:
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi:
                [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] setSuspended:NO];
                break;
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable:
            default:
                [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] setSuspended:YES];
                break;
        }
    }];
```

but I obtain a crash with this message, where is the problem?

```
[NSOperationQueue reachabilityManager]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get the `reachabilityManager` from the main `NSOperationQueue`, which doesn't have it. You should be using `[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager]` to get the `reachabilityManager` instance.

---

So:

```
[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) { ...
```

---

Also, consider the logic of trying to suspend the main queue. What you probably want to be doing is getting the `operationQueue` from your `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` instance and suspending that...

Comment: and how I can get it?

Comment: ok and this '[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager]' work for the '[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]'???

Comment: The reachability manager has nothing to do with an operation queue. And it seems unlikely that you should be trying to suspend the main queue...

Comment: So should I use the 'AFHTTPRequestOperationManager' to do my batch operations right? and not simply the NSOperationQueue

Comment: ok, but I don't understand because in the guide lines of AFNetworking 2.0 for the batch operations in suggested to do that I do and not to use the manager

Comment: Ok, but you can't do that if you intend to suspend the queue, you need to use the manager queue or a custom queue you create (and retain). If you were to suspend the main queue the app stops working (from a user point of view).

Comment: ah ok ok yes you're right. Then I should transform my code for the manager thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
     [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
            switch (status) {
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN:
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi:
                [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] setSuspended:NO];
                break;
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable:
            default:
                [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] setSuspended:YES];
                break;
        }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify @simalone's answer to:

```
[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] setSuspended:![AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager].reachable];
    }
}];
```

@Wain is right though, suspending the mainQueue doesn't sound like a great plan.

Use `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` and assign your own operationQueue.